# vuex store doesn't update component

Tags: javascript, vuex

I'm new to vue, so I'm probably making a rookie error.

I have a root vue element - raptor.js:

```
const Component = {
el: '#app',
store,
data: {
    productList: store.state.productlist
},
beforeCreate: function () {
    return store.dispatch('getProductList', 'getTrendingBrands');
},
updated: function (){
    console.log(111);
    startSlider();
}
};
const vm = new Vue(Component);
```

Using this template

```
<div class="grid-module-single popular-products" id="app">
<div class="row">
    <div class="popular-items-slick col-xs-12">
        <div v-for="product in productList">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My store is very simple store/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import model from '../../utilities/model';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    productlist: []
},
mutations: {
    setProductList(state, data) {
        state.productlist = data;
    }
},
actions: {
    getProductList({ commit }, action) {
        return model.products().then(data => commit('setProductList', data));
    }
}
});
```

In my vuex devtool, I can see, that the store is being updated
https://www.screencast.com/t/UGbw7JyHS3

but my component is not being updated:
https://www.screencast.com/t/KhXQrePEd

**Question:**

I can see from the devtools, that my code is working. The store is being updated with data. My component is not being updated,however. I thought it was enough just to add this in the data property on the component:

```
data: {
    productList: store.state.productlist
}
```

but apparently the data object doesn't seem to be automatically synced with the store. So either I'm doing a complete vue no-no somewhere, or I need to tweak the code a bit. Anyway can anyone help me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Figured it out myself. Just had to replace the components data part with a computed method:

data:

```
data: {
  productList: store.state.productlist
}
```

and replace it with.

```
computed: {
    productList () {
        return store.state.productlist;
    }
},
```

Comment: Is this way documented?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution in the documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html

Comment: Is it necessary to replace it? Or can we keep both `data` and `computed`

Comment: Yes, you can use both like this example from Vue docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html. It's used in the example to avoid large expression in {{ }} operator.

Comment: I had forgotten to add `state` between `store` and `productlist`. Gratitude @MartinKure!

Comment: this worked for me as well ```const loggedIn = computed(() => store.getters['auth/authenticated']);``` now updates after the store value gets changed.

Answer (score 5):

data only work once on component before render, so you can use computed instead.
like above answer, or you can use mapstate

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
...
computed: mapState({
  productList: state => state.productList
})
```

Comment: Now it's `mapState` with a capital S.

Answer (score 4):

First - use getter to do this `mapGetters`, also you need to watch this property somehow, you can set store subscription or just with watch method trough component.

```
 this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {    
   if (mutation.type === 'UPDATE_DATA') {
      ...
   }
 }
```

Comment: hmm.. interesting. But where do you subscribe to the changes? In the component in `mounted()`?

Comment: proper way is to use it in `created()` hook, but guess that in `mounted` will work too

Answer (score 0):

For composition API with script setup, i.e., `<script setup>`, try this.

```
const productList = computed(() => store.state.productlist);
```

Answer (score -2):

You are calling the store into the productList data property in the wrong way.

You can try it:

```
data: {
  productList: $store.state.productlist
}
```

Otherwise you have to import store in each component that are using the store.