# vue vuex: display an updateable state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

while trying to get an updateable data in a tag I am only receiving the initial data,
I can see the data updating in the debugger.
and after changeing the state I can not display the new data:

I'm doing all the update thing in another component I only need to display the updated data from store

**component.vue**

```
<template lang="js">
    <div>
        <h1>hello {{ store.getters.myData}}</h1>

  <a><router-link to="/register">Go to Sign up</router-link></a>
  <a><router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link></a>
  <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import store from "../store";
export default {
};
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const state = { data: 'initial data'}
const getters = { myData(state){ return state.data; } }
const mutations = { UPDATE_DATA(state, data){ state.data = data; } }
const actions = { setData(data) { store.commit("UPDATE_DATA", data);} }

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
})

export default store
```

Comment: @EDG956 yeah sorry about that, I made an update and also checking your reference

Comment: I've tried this line but nothing was happend:
<h1 :key="this.$store.state.data">hello {{ this.$store.state.data }}</h1>

Comment: I think you should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192855/vuex-store-doesnt-update-component)

Comment: @EDG956 take a look at my edit section

Comment: @EDG956 ok I tried but still nothing

Comment: @yaronshamul You have to create getters in the store and use the getter in your component to display updated data in the UI.

Comment: @H_H ok I changed it like this:
        <h1>hello {{ this.$store.getters.getData }}</h1>
it is still do nothing

Comment: @yaronshamul Add computed property in your component and return this data - this.$store.getters.getData and use the computed property in template

Comment: @H_H already done but it is not calling the getter

Comment: @yaronshamul create a fiddle of your use case and will try to solve it

Comment: @H_H thank you for your offer unforuanately it was very difficult to do it, but you can see the pastebin I posted bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `vuex` mapGetters function to display your data.

In your component file import your getter inside the computed property

Import mapGetters with `import {mapGetters} from "vuex";`

```js
computed: {
     ...mapGetters({
        myData: 'store/myData'
     })
}
```

Your data should be updated any times your store is updated

Comment: can you please take a look on this [link](https://pastebin.com/HNiy52r2)

Comment: ok I removed one of these mapGetters wrapers and it doesn't give me an error but still doesn't work as wanted:
[see this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/v1aryWNJ)

Comment: Have a look a this [code pen](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-forked-22tp3?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) and tell me if it answer your question about how to connect with the store

Comment: can you please add some change so it will feat vue version 3.x?

Comment: Here is the app using version 3.0.0 : [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/watching-a-store-getter-in-vue-3-forked-8jpeb)

Comment: it might sound a bit wrong but I think my dependencies were wrong. one of [this](https://pastebin.com/jp8TyngJ) broked this functionallity